# Ensure cluster message sent are received

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use cluster library to start different code.

The master forks, then sends a message to the cluster with the file to start, which is then `require()` and started.

I have made redirections of the different `process.send()` of the slaves to allow them to communicate.

My problem is, I have a code that is long to start, and is supposed to receive a message from another code to start correctly. The problem is, since it didn't started at time, `process.on('message')` hadn't load, and so the message is lost.

Is there a way to know when that happen, so I can try to send it again?

```
.________.-------------------------------.
| master |<--------------------. message |
|________|                     |         |
 | | start                     |         |
 | |_________________________. |         |
 |                           | |         |
 V                           V |         /
.______.                  ._______.      / Lost because long didn t load at time
| long |                  | short |      |
|______|                  |_______|      |
  ^                                      |
  |______________________________________|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to send a message to your workers where you tell them which file to start. you could just add a config while forking:

```
cluster.fork('yourConfig': {"fileToStart": "someFileName"})
```

and then in your worker:

```
var config = JSON.parse(process.env.yourConfig)
require(config.fileToStart);
```

there is also the possibilty to get an 'online' event, when a new worker is forked. so what you need to do is to not send an message from your master in your worker when he is not online, just queue these messages, and send them when your worker is online. `cluster.workers` is one of the methods to work with here.

i think all what you need is something i've already done and published to the npm-registry:

the cluster-wrapper:

[various-cluster](https://npmjs.org/package/various-cluster)

the messaging between workers:

[msghub](https://npmjs.org/package/msghub)

the github repos are linked, take a look at the code, or just use both modules ;-)

Comment: +1 for the config trick, I never heard of that and is just wonderful for my use. The online event won t work for my case, since on 4 different codes, only one actually use internet, so that don t help me a lot. Your modules seems interesting, but I can t use third party code on this project (for the same reason I can t show code).

Comment: there is no +1 klicked on my answer ;-) i'm also fine with learning or even copying parts of my code, that should help you a lot i think...

Comment: Doh! Just started to adapt my codes to the config, and saw that the code that didn t received message was so because I somehow mixed my start event with the message event. I ll accept your answer since it would have been the best if I was on a personnal project.